# How to make arrow-shaped background with css or svg?

Tags: css, svg, shapes, css-shapes

I'd like to simply get pointed to the right direction... I have to code a css or svg background like this:

[image]

Also please note the rounded tip.
Should I use pure css (and in this case, what rules should I look into)? Should I use svg some way? Where would you start from?

Comment: hello, there is also the oldish transformed pseudo that is usable https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/LYmWaZY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would first design the arrow in software like Adobe Illustrator, export it as an svg, open the svg-file in a text file editor and then copying the svg-code from the svg file (in the text editor) into your HTML-document.

In your HTML-document, you can put the svg on top of the background, and then put text on top of the svg

```
<div id="background-with-arrow">
    <p>This is your text</p>

    <svg x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 1000 500">
        <path class="st0" d="M0,0v500h750l247.7-244.5c3.1-3.1,3.1-7.8,0-10.9L750,0H0z"/>
    </svg>
</div>
```

Or you can even design the arrow **with** text in Illustrator, and do the same process of exporting as svg, and importing the svg code into your HTML.

I've made a [quick demo](https://codepen.io/MikaTheDesigner/pen/RwypvLX) here